# Open Office save file without functions

Tags: openoffice.org, openoffice-calc

I want to save a open office calc documents without all the functions in it to prevent that the functions calculate all the time I open it. Im using a template document where the functions are in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To prevent functions from calculating, go to `Tools` -> `Cell Contents` and uncheck `AutoCalculate`.  Then save the template.  When you create a document using the template, the `AutoCalculate` setting will be off.

To calculate functions, either press <kbd>Ctrl-Shift-F9</kbd> or turn `AutoCalculate` back on.

Comment: Thanks, that was was I've searching for